# Can't run node-mapnik-sample-code

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik, node-js

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.
I installed mapnik from packages as described here: https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation
now I want to run node-mapnik-sample-code from here: https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik-sample-code

The example is:

```
node ./examples/simple/render.js examples/stylesheet.xml map.png
```

but if I run this command it shows the errormessage

```
/home/tiletest/node-mapnik/examples/simple/render.js:27
map.loadSync(stylesheet);
    ^
Error: Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in Layer at line 11 of     'examples/stylesheet.xml'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tiletest/node-mapnik/examples/simple/render.js:27:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

do I have to edit the stylesheet.xml or how can I run the example ?

Comment: I don't know the linked tut, please try to follow the guide at www.switch2osm.org to setup a local OSM rendering stack. Then test it with the local tileserver. If it works you can go further and test the node.js examples. Sorry but I never used node.js, so I can't provide further help :/

Comment: yes you can edit the xml to change the shapefile and its path as you wish.

Comment: I don't know what should be changed, the path to the shapefile is ok

Answer (score 1):

The traceback tell you that the shapefile could not be parsed. The first things to check are:

1. In stylesheet.xml the datasource is defined by:

   `<Parameter name="file">data/world_merc.shp</Parameter>`

   Be sure that this shapefile is located in this path in your
   computer.
2. Be sure that the mapnik shapefile plugin is well installed by
   doing:

   ```
   $ python -c "from mapnik import DatasourceCache as c; print ','.join(c.plugin_names())"
   ```

   If you see shape in the list, it's good. Otherwise, you will have to re-install Mapnik with this plugin.

Otherwise, the error could be harder to find and you should probably try following the guide at [www.switch2osm.org](http://www.switch2osm.org)

Comment: I checked the input from the parameter name, the shapefile is located int this path. when executing  `python -c "from mapnik import DatasourceCache as c; print ','.join(c.plugin_names())"` it shows `csv,gdal,geojson,ogr,osm,postgis,raster,shape,sqlite` so I think the shapefile plugin is available

Comment: have you built mapnik from github source or did you use apt-get for installation?

Comment: I used apt-get for installation

Comment: You can try to run the [shapefile_test.py](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/tests/python_tests/shapefile_test.py) to see if your shapefile plugin works well. If yes, than the problem is probably in node-mapnik-sample-code

Comment: ok tried it. it prints `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shapefile_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from nose.tools import *
ImportError: No module named nose.tools
` don't know what's that for a module

Comment: ok nose is installed, I must check how to to install missing utilities module which is also needed to run `shapefile_test.py`